# Is it possible to apply additional css properties such as border radius around candles?

Tags: lightweight-charts

So far, I've searched the documentation, discord, and here, and have not been able to find additional documentation and / or workarounds the alter the style (besides colors and border visibility).

Answer (score 0):

No, this is impossible right now.